# Unable to build libraries using cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

I am trying to build a python code for numerical applications, and has written a cython segment for a particular bottleneck section of the code. However, when I try to build the extension, it return the following error

```
error: could not create 'plank/routines/overlap.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory
```

The setup.py file looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy 
import os 

os.environ["CPPFLAGS"]  =   os.getenv("CPPFLAGS", "") + "-I" + numpy.get_include()

routines    =   [Extension('plank.routines.overlap',['./overlap.pyx'])]

setup(
        name                =   'plank',
        version             =   '1.0.0',
        packages            =   find_packages(),
        license             =   'BSD-3',
        python_requires     =   ">=3.4",
        install_requires    =   ['cython', 'numpy', 'scipy'],
        ext_modules         =   cythonize(routines, compiler_directives  = {'linetrace': True, 'language_level':'3'}),
        include_dirs        =   [numpy.get_include()]        
        )
```

The overlap.pyx file looks like this

```
import cython   as  cython
import numpy    as  np
cimport numpy   as  np 
from scipy.special  import comb as comb
from scipy.special  import factorial2 as fact2
from libc.math      cimport exp, pow

@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef double overlapgtos(double center1, double exponent1, int shell1, \
                        double center2, double exponent2, int shell2, \
                        double gcenter):
    cdef double overlap    =   0.0
    cdef int counter1, counter2
    cdef double ss  =   0.0
    for counter1 in range(0,shell1+1):
        for counter2 in range(0,shell2+1):
            if ((counter1+counter2)%2 == 0):
                ss  =   comb(shell1,counter1,exact=True)   
                ss  *=  comb(shell2,counter2,exact=True)
                ss  *=  fact2(counter1+counter2-1)
                ss  /=  pow(2.0*(exponent1+exponent2),0.5*(counter1+counter2))
                ss  *=  pow(gcenter-center1,shell1-counter1)
                ss  *=  pow(gcenter-center2,shell2-counter2)
                overlap +=  ss

    return overlap
```

Am I missing something? I can confirm that the cython code works fine in the native python form. This led me to guess that the error is probably from the setup.py section. Any advices is much appreciated.

Comment: `plank/routines/overlap.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` -> does the path exist ?

Comment: Yes, It exists.

Comment: Your code is trying to create smthing in that path. does ur code have access to it ? If it does not, it will report it as not found. Try running your setup using sudo access if the path can only be accessed via root. `Warning: Do this only if you are sure that the setup file is safe to run as root.`

Comment: When I tried running the command as ```sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace --user``` It gave the following error ImportError: No module named Cython.Build

Comment: Ah. thats because your python in root does not have cython installed. You probably have that installed in the python you are using under your user. My suggestion is instead of running as root, try to give permission to that path to your code script. As you can see, it is a permission issue as this time, it did not give a no such dir/file found error. So fix that and you should be fine

Comment: Ill give you a hint - use virtual envs. That way all your libs will be in a path that your vitual env can access.

Comment: @leoOrion Thanks for the pointer. It solved my problem.

Comment: I put a dunder init file in the directory and get the same error, when I deleted it the setup worked fine.